# Unreadable text characters on emacs and some other programs

Tags: linux, emacs, xorg

I'm using VNC on a remote host with Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7. Whenever I run "emacs" I get this output:

```
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-courier-medium-r-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-medium-r-*--*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1" to type FontStruct
```

And Emacs window has just box shapes as characters:
[image]

I can work around by manually passing font option to emacs as explained in this post:
[Can't export emacs display on ssh](https://superuser.com/questions/247435/cant-export-emacs-display-on-ssh)

But some other enterprise software that I need to work with also has the same problem. Unfortunately it doesn't have an option to define fonts like emacs. It looks like I have an issue with my local default font settings. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my own question. I can fix the issue for the current vnc session by entering these on terminal:

```
xset +fp /usr/share/X11/fonts/misc/,/usr/share/X11/fonts/75dpi/,/usr/share/X11/fonts/100dpi/,/usr/share/X11/fonts/Type1/,/usr/share/X11/fonts/misc,/usr/share/X11/fonts/100dpi,/usr/share/fonts/default/Type1
xset fp rehash
```

However, I lose these settings when I open a new vnc session. If someone knows how to make these settings permanent, that would be deeply appreciated.